# Last Element of Vector Changes After Making Copy and Popping from Copy

Tags: c++, vector, reference

In C++, I have a function that is supposed to split a vector into its last element and the rest of the vector. However, I make the following observations which I cannot explain:

```
function(vector<int> indeces){
    // indeces = [1,2,3]
    vector<int> indeces_ = indeces;
    // indeces = [1,2,3] = indeces_
    indeces_.pop_back();
    // indeces = [1,2,3], indeces_ = [1,2]   
    // BUT: *indeces.end() != 3 but some unrelated integer
}
```

Comment: This is not c++. But despite the wrong function definition, does the operator= take a rvalue by some means when assigning it to indeces_? Have you debugged that. Also post minimal reproducible code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is wrong. You cannot use `end()` that way:

> Returns an iterator referring to the *past-the-end* element in the vector container.
>
> The past-the-end element is the theoretical element that would follow the last element in the vector. It does not point to any element, and thus shall not be dereferenced.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using the `std::vector` class right.

`void std::vector<type>::pop_back()` deletes the last element in the collection, effectively reducing the container size by one.

**The function `std::vector<type>::end()` returns an iterator that is in this case a pointer pointing to an element past the last element in the collection.**

Also, there are a couple of issues with the code you have posted. 
A function is expected to return a type. If you want to return nothing, then return void.